# Java pointer or node assignment understanding wrong?

Tags: java, pointers, tree, nodes

A problem I'm solving is asking to insert a node inside a binary search tree, then return the root of the entire binary tree at the end.

The issue I seem to be having is saving the inserted node inside the original tree given it's root. My code is below:

```
static Node Insert(Node root,int value) {
    insertAux(root, value);
    return root;
}

static void insertAux(Node root, int value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node();
        root.data = value;
        root.left = root.right = null;
    } else {
        if (value > root.data) {
            insertAux(root.right, value);
        } else {
            insertAux(root.left, value);
        }
    }
}
```

When I test this with the following tree:

```
    4
   / \
  2   7
 / \
1   3
```

it should result in:

```
      4
   /    \
  2      7
 / \    /
1   3  6
```

I have tested this and my insertAux function does in fact assign root to a new Node() and the data for that node to the value 6 when it hits the null case at the end of the function. I have also tested and made sure that my Insert function returns the original root at the end of the entire call. However when I try to see if insertAux has assigned root.right.left to a new Node() and its data to 6 inside of the Insert function, I get a null pointer exception where root.right.left is null. Why is this, is my understanding of pointers or node assignment for Java wrong?

Comment: Java is pass by value. Initializing the root variable in insertAux won't have any impact on the root variable in Insert. Also, please respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: what did opmt do wrong java naming convention wise, is it the capital i in Insert? I looked at this link for java naming conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: The reason why I had the i capitalized in Insert is because the problem that I got this from(HackerRank) named it with the capital i, otherwise their compiler wouldn't detect the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static Node insertAux(Node root, int value) {
if (root == null) {
    root = new Node();
    root.data = value;
    root.left = root.right = null;
} else {
    if (value > root.data) {
        root.right = insertAux(root.right, value);
    } else {
        root.left = insertAux(root.left, value);
    }
}

return root;
}
```

Your insertAux() method should be like this.

First of all it should have a return type as Node.

What your doing wrong here is that you are not creating a link between the parent node and child node. So in your case, a new Node with data 6 is created **but it is actually never assigned to its parent**.

So you need to assign the newly created node by returning it and assigning it to parent.In your method here

```
if (value > root.data) {
        root.right = insertAux(root.right, value);
    } else {
        root.left = insertAux(root.left, value);
    }
```

Comment: great answer, thanks for the full directions. That last part of assigning root.right and root.left was very helpful :) you rock

Comment: Thanks for appreciation! You can like and follow my blog www.learningarsenal.info You will surely like it

Answer (score 1):

Java pass parameters by value (i.e not by reference), internal assignment to `root` is lost after return from function. Try return in different way, maybe

```
static Node insertAux(Node root, int value) {
```